# Material Components Chip colour styling

Tags: android, material-components-android

In my XML I'm just declaring a `ChipGroup` as follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then adding each `Chip` dynamically:

```
ChipGroup chipGroup = findViewById(R.id.chipGroup);
for (String name : names) {
    Chip chip = new Chip(activity);
    chip.setText(name);
    chipGroup.addView(chip);
}
```

The colour of a selected Chip (light green below) seems to be coming from the `colorSecondaryContainer` attribute (I know that, because when I change that in my theme, the Chip colour changes).  I'd rather it came from `colorPrimaryContainer`, but it would be OK as-is except that the text colour does not suit `colorSecondaryContainer`... in particular, the text colour does *not* seem to be coming from `colorOnSecondaryContainer` as I would expect, because `colorOnSecondaryContainer` is dark in my theme, but what I'm seeing is a light text colour on a light chip colour (and the text colour is light regardless of checked status):

[image]

How do I make my Chip style comply with my material theme in general, without having to resort to setting this stuff via setters like `chip.setTextColor()` etc?  I don't declare any Chip via XML so I can't override the style in the individual declaration either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Chip Style in `theme.xml` file

**ChipCustomStyle in theme.xml**

```
<style name="ChipCustomStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chip_background_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/chip_text_color</item>
    <item name="chipCornerRadius">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Create `color` resource folder under `res` and Add `chip_background_color.xml` for chip background color and `chip_text_color.xml` for chip text color

**chip_background_color.xml in color folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/green" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

**chip_text_color.xml in color folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

**Create attr.xml in values folder and then add CustomChipChoiceStyle attribute in attr.xml**

```
<resources>
    <attr name="CustomChipChoiceStyle" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

Add `CustomChipChoiceStyle` in your current activity theme in `theme.xml` file

```
 <item name="CustomChipChoiceStyle">@style/ChipCustomStyle</item>
```

Now add `CustomChipChoiceStyle` style to your Chip in Kotlin file, Example code:

```
val chipGroup = findViewById<ChipGroup>(R.id.chipGroup)
for (name in names) {
   val chip = Chip(this, null, R.attr.CustomChipChoiceStyle)
   //val chip = Chip(this)
   chip.text = name
   chipGroup.addView(chip)
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I had already tried creating `chip_background_color.xml` and `chip_text_color.xml` resources, and settings these with `chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.chip_background_color)` and `chip.setTextColor(ActivityCompat.getColorStateList(mContext, R.color.chip_text_color))`... I would prefer your approach of referring to a style when creating the `Chip`... but with my approach I also get a stroke around that Chip that is only visible when the Chip is not selected... I have tried setting `chipStrokeWidth` in the style but that stroke appears even for selected Chips.

Comment: You can set `chipStrokeColor` same as `chipBackgroundColor` in style